# Angular Interceptor hanging

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've an interceptor which I've created with the aim of having it append a query string element to every request. To know which value to append to the query string I have to connect to a service, return an observable from that service, I then switchmap to return the HTTPRequest that the interceptor is expecting.

```
@Injectable()
export class PermCheckInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public userService: UserService) {}
    intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , handler: HttpHandler): Observable < httpEvent < any >> {
        return this userService.currentUser.pipe(
        switchMap(curUser => {
                return handler.handle(reg.clone {
                    setParams: {
                        "perm": curUser.hasPerms ? 'true' : 'false'
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
```

Currently this code throws no errors but when running the site it just hangs, which I presume is because the interceptor is never resolving. The line:

```
userService.currentUser.pipe
```

from the code above is connecting to a service and returning an observable which is created from a Subject (using .asObservable() ).

My guess is that the observable is not yet triggered or available at the time the interceptor first runs, so it just hangs. This is a guess though.

Does anything look wrong with the code above? Is there a way to check that the observable has a value before proceeding with the interceptor or is there a better way in general of doing this?

Comment: Could it be that you're missing a . on line 5 of your snippet, or is is just incorrectly written code sample:
return this userService

Comment: If you're using rxjs V6+ you'll need to use pipes like `pipe(operator functions...)` instead of chaining. Before V6 it looks like you're missing a `.` .

Comment: Bad code typing by me, I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first step would be to debug to ensure you know where the problem is. As you say, it does seem likely that `userService.currentUser` is not emitting a value after the interceptor subscribes.

Use your preferred debugging method after this statement `switchMap(curUser => {` to check that it is actually emitting and what the value is. Also check that the `intercept()` is getting called in the first place (I assume you have already configured that but just in case).

If I were to habit a guess, `userService` is using a `Subject` and you are emitting a value, but it is only emitting once and then by the time the interceptor subscribes the value has already been emitted and thus nothing else comes down the stream. By the looks of your code, I would probably recommend using a `ReplaySubject` which replays a number of previous values whenever a new subscriber is added. (Read more: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject)

So when you instantiate your subject in the user service you can do:

```
this.userSubject = new ReplaySubject(1);
```

The `1` passed to the `ReplaySubject` constructor dictates how many values will be replayed when a new subscriber subscribes. So when the interceptor subscribes it will immediately get the last value that was emitted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your suggestions out. I'm using a BehaviorSubject which is seeded with 'null' so that could be what's emitted. Is there a way of ignoring anything until a value is produced by the observable? As in, if the interceptor doesn't detect a value then proceed as normal?

Comment: So, I've added a console.log after the pipe (as a tap) and also after the switchmap, neither are hit so it's definitely not emitting. TBH that's not surprising as the app hasn't properly loaded when the interceptor is first hit, but I'd love a way for this interceptor to just pass through until values started emitting from the subscription

Comment: I mean using a behaviour subject should work in that case, since it emits an initial value, and you can just check for that initial value and let the request pass through. Another thing you can also do is use [timeout](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/timeout).

Comment: That's exactly what I did, thanks - it worked.